# What is the "ExcelApiUndo" requirement set?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

While looking into the `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported()` API to see if there was a way to get the latest supported requirement set for `ExcelApi`, I found the set of them under `Office.context.requirements._setMap._sets`. Inside that was another one called `ExcelApiUndo`:

[image: image showing the values under Office.context.requirements._setMap._sets]

I cannot find any information about this requirement set in the Office JS docs, what exactly is it?

Comment: Try posting this to the `OfficeJS` repo at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/discussions .

Comment: Thanks @EugeneAstafiev, I was not aware of this community